# How can I use a single Riverpod provider for multiple widgets with independent state in Flutter using Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I’m using Riverpod provider to manage the state of 4 containers in Flutter that changes the state of the container to a different colour. However, I might need more containers in the future and creating a new provider for each container doesn't sound right. Is there a way to use a single provider for multiple containers while keeping their state independent?

They way I am going about this is creating 4 independent providers for each container, this of course works but I want to add way more containers in the future so the code is getting unnecessarily large.

Comment: If you have many providers with the same functionality but tied to a separate specific instance, that's a perfect example of when to use a family key.

Comment: Hey @Ruble, I was able to figure it out. Like Randal mentioned, I should be using a family key.

Comment: @Karthik S , Great, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Create as many providers as you need.
2. Create a model that has as many fields as you have containers and manage it with a single `StateProvider`. Then it is worth looking at the **freezed** package, which will keep the object immutable and the correct `hashCode/==`.
3. Depending on the situation, you can override the provider through `ProviderScope(...)`

```dart
final containerProvider = Provider((ref) => 1);

Widget build(context, ref) {
  return ProviderScope(
            overrides: [
              containerProvider.overrideWithValue(2),
            ],
            child: Container(...),
          ),
}
```

It turns out that each container will be overridden with its own value.

4. Use the modifier `.family` for the provider to provide the custom value